# CLI arguments that take their own arguments with Clap

Tags: rust, clap

My program takes several file names as command line arguments, for example:

`./myProgram -F file1 file2`

This simple case works fine with Clap, [in fact it's the doc example of `Arg::multiple()`](https://docs.rs/clap/2.33.0/clap/struct.Arg.html#method.multiple).

However, I'd also like each file to take arguments of its own, which changes the behavior of that particular file. Simplified example:

`./myProgram -F --name file1 ---format csv --priority 2 -F --name file2 --priority 1`

Here, file1 has a higher priority and a different format from file2.

Simply using Arg::multiple() no longer works, since the file-specific arguments (format, priority) get parsed as independent arguments, with no way to know which file they belong to.

[Arg::allow_hyphen_values()](https://docs.rs/clap/2.33.0/clap/struct.Arg.html#method.allow_hyphen_values) *seems* to get me part of the way there. But it just parses every occurrence of `--name`, `file1`, `--format` etc as a value to the -F option, with no way to know which `--priority` argument belongs to which file. I thought about using a different syntax for the file specific arguments and parsing those manually, but with this restriction, I can't even do that.

Is there any way to to do this with Clap?